# Split single column in rows separted out by mulitple columns according to string - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have 2 tables requiring string split. The result table will split the string to create new year, make, model columns. Here are the sample 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    sku varchar(50), 
    Conca varchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (sku, Conca)
VALUES ('AVS1234','Game;Consoles/Year;2001/ Year;2002/ Year;2006/ Year;2007/ Year;2009/ Year;2011/Make;XBox/Model;100/'),
       ('AVS1234','Game;Consoles/Year;2016/Make;Nintendo/Model;DX/'),
       ('AVS1234','Game;Consoles/Year;2001/ Year;2002/ Year;2006/ Year;2007/ Year;2009/ Year;2011/Make;PS/Model;300/Model;500/');

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    sku2 varchar(50), 
    Conca2 varchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO Table2 (sku2, Conca2)
VALUES ('AVS1234','<tr><td>2011 </td><td>Xbox </td><td>100; Notes : 2 pc.; Stainless</td></tr>'), 
       ('AVS1234','<tr><td>2005 </td><td>Xbox </td><td>100; Notes : 2 pc.; Stainless</td></tr>'), 
       ('AVS1234','<tr><td>2016 </td><td>Xbox </td><td>300</td></tr>');
```

Intended result table1

```
        Sku     year    make   model
        --------------------------
        avs1234 2001    XBox    100
        avs1234 2002    XBox    100
        avs1234 2006    XBox    100
        avs1234 2007    XBox    100
        avs1234 2009    XBox    100
        avs1234 2011    XBox    100
        AVS1234 2016    Nintendo    DX
        AVS1234 2001    PS      300
        AVS1234 2002    PS      300
        AVS1234 2006    PS      300
        AVS1234 2007    PS      300
        AVS1234 2009    PS      300
        AVS1234 2011    PS      300
        AVS1234 2001    PS      500
        AVS1234 2002    PS      500
        AVS1234 2006    PS      500
        AVS1234 2007    PS      500
        AVS1234 2009    PS      500
        AVS1234 2011    PS      500
```

Intended result table2

```
        Sku       year  make   model  Notes
        ------------------------------------
        avs1234   2001  XBox    100   2 pc.; Stainless
        avs1234   2002  XBox    100   2 pc.; Stainless
        AVS1234   2005  Xbox    100   2 pc.; Stainless
        AVS1234   2016  Xbox    300
```

First I thought to try the position/trim method of:

```
Cross Apply 
    (Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
```

But the # years could range from 1950s to 2018 and beyond. So this will create way too many "pos".

To the best of my capabilities I then tried:

```
with firstpass as
(
    SELECT A.sku,  
           Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
    FROM  
        (SELECT sku,  
                Cast('<M>' + replace((Select replace(Conca,'year','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</M><M>')+'</M>' as xml) as Data
         FROM  table1) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY 
        Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT
    *, Year = SUBSTRING([data], 1 ,
            case when  CHARINDEX('/', [data] ) = 0 then LEN([data]) 
            else CHARINDEX('/', [data]) -1 end)
                   from firstpass
```

I can't quite figure out where to go next.... Please assist.

Comment: Honestly, that data is in a terrible condition to be used by SQL server. You could, probably,, create the intended result for the first table, but the second will be a problem.  SQL Server had no context of html, so you won't have an easy way of stripping the data out of the mark up. I think you might be better of using a text parsing tool, rather than SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu although mainly correct a way of doing it would be regex and pattern matching using patindex, eitherway its horrible and feels wrong.

Comment: also, why are you saving html markup in the table anyway??

Comment: I was thinking of using replace to remove all the html tags from table 2. Any suggestions for table 1 though?

Comment: I've not got time to test or write a query out, but I would use a couple of `SFRING_SPLIT`s to get the first result. Firstly on `/` and then `;`. You'll need a further `CROSS APPLY` and some `CASE` expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If open to a Table-Valued helper Function.  I modified a split/parse function to accept two non-like delimeters because I tired of extracting strings  (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc).

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fd1ab2608b6df23dc190d4fe6fa50061)**

```
Select SKU
      ,Year  = B.RetVal
      ,Make  = C.RetVal
      ,Model = D.RetVal
 From  Table1 A
 Cross Apply  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]('/'+A.Conca+'/','Year;','/')  B
 Cross Apply  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]('/'+A.Conca+'/','Make;' ,'/') C
 Cross Apply  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]('/'+A.Conca+'/','Model;','/') D


Select SKU2
      ,Year  = XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,Make  = XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Model = ltrim(rtrim(left(XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[3]','varchar(max)'),charindex(';',XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[3]','varchar(max)')+';')-1)))
      ,Notes = ltrim(rtrim(substring(XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[3]','varchar(max)'),charindex(';',XMLData.value('tr[1]/td[3]','varchar(max)')+';')+1,100)))
 From  Table2
 Cross Apply (values (cast(Conca2 as xml)) )B(XMLdata)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **Edit - You can use the TVF for table2 as well**

```
Select SKU2
      ,B.Year
      ,B.Make
      ,Model = ltrim(rtrim(left(B.Model,charindex(';',B.Model+';')-1)))
      ,Notes = ltrim(rtrim(substring(B.Model,charindex(';',B.Model+';')+1,100)))
 From  Table2 A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Year  = max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)
                      ,Make  = max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal end)
                      ,Model = max(case when RetSeq=3 then RetVal end)
                 From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.Conca2,'<td>','</td>')  
             )B
```

Comment: I am getting: "Invalid object name 'dbo.tvf-Str-Extract'"

Comment: @wsi  You need to add the function.  Run the create function first

Comment: @ John Cappelletti Please see the modification i made to data which now yields duplicate results https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0f8a6b2dffb5f46748a565749047f1a4

Comment: My dataset is quite large (over 1MM rows). With dups query is taking  too long. Please assist.

Comment: @Wsi I would suggest that since the data has such a horrible format, that you let the process run and store the results.  Fixing 1MM+ rows will have a one time cost, but well worth it in the long run.